# PHPUnit - How to mock the class inside another class's method?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

How can I mock the class inside another class's method?

For instance,

```
protected function buildRequest($params)
{
    return new \Request();
}

public function getPayload($params)
{
    $request = $this->buildRequest($params);
    ....
}
```

Can I mock `buildRequest`?

I need to test this method `getPayload($params)` but I get this error:

```
Class 'Request' not found in...
```

Answer (score 5):

One option is to introduce a factory that would create a `Request` instance, and inject the factory into your class. You'd be able to stub the factory and whatever it creates.

Another option is to extend the class you're testing, override your `buildRequest()` method to return a mock and test your class through this extension.

Finally, PHPUnit offers you the ability to create so called partial mocks:

```
$request = new \Request();
$params = [1, 2, 3];

$foo = $this->getMock(Foo::class, ['buildRequest']);
$foo->expects($this->any())
    ->method('buildRequest')
    ->with($this->equalTo($params))
    ->willReturn($request);

$payload = $foo->getPayload($params);
```

However, your `Request` class doesn't seem to exist or be autoloaded. You'll need to solve this problem first.